# Need to add tags and normal text in same input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I need to  add tags and text in the same input box. The normal text can be delete a character at once. The tags which will be selected from a particular set of words which are pre defined will be deleted all at once. The normal text and tags will be on the same box.

The link to fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/akhilsahu/t7m2nvcn/)
So far I have tried to

```js
document.querySelector('.selectable-icons').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 
    document.querySelector('[contenteditable]').appendChild(e.target.cloneNode(true));
  
});


document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    // Check for a backspace
    if (event.which == 8) {
        s = window.getSelection();
        r = s.getRangeAt(0)
        el = r.startContainer.parentElement
        // Check if the current element is the .label
        if (el.classList.contains('label')) {
            // Check if we are exactly at the end of the .label element
            if (r.startOffset == r.endOffset && r.endOffset == el.textContent.length) {
                // prevent the default delete behavior
                event.preventDefault();
                if (el.classList.contains('highlight')) {
                    // remove the element
                    el.remove();
                } else {
                    el.classList.add('highlight');
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    event.target.querySelectorAll('span.label.highlight').forEach(function(el) { el.classList.remove('highlight');})
});
```

```css
[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.4em 0;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
}
img {
  vertical-align: top;
  max-height: 1.4em;
  max-width: 1.4em;
}
.selectable-icons img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.label.highlight {
    background: #E1ECF4;
    border: 1px dotted #39739d;
}

span.label  {
    background: #E1ECF4;
    border: 1px dotted #39739d;
}
```

```html
<p>Just click on an icon to add it.</p>

<div class="custom-input">
  <div class="selectable-icons">
      <span class="label"> Tag </span> 
       <span class="label"> Tag 2 </span> 
      <span class="label">Tag 3</span>  
  </div>
  <div contenteditable="true">
    You can type here. Add an icon.
  </div>
</div>
```

add tags but the issue is when click on the tag it adds it to the text box and when I write text after that tag this all is added to same span of tag and Tag + Text all is deleted together rather I need text to be deleted one character at once and the tags all at once. Please suggest a better way to achieve this with textarea instead of div.

Note: If I change tag data in span which are also editable. Also reflects in the editable div of tags and text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the *tag* is added to the `div`, set its `contenteditable` attribute to `false`:

```
el.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```

I hope that solves your problem - see demo below:

```js
document.querySelector('.selectable-icons').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var el = e.target.cloneNode(true);
  el.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
  document.querySelector('[contenteditable]').appendChild(el);

});


document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  // Check for a backspace
  if (event.which == 8) {
    s = window.getSelection();
    r = s.getRangeAt(0)
    el = r.startContainer.parentElement
    // Check if the current element is the .label
    if (el.classList.contains('label')) {
      // Check if we are exactly at the end of the .label element
      if (r.startOffset == r.endOffset && r.endOffset == el.textContent.length) {
        // prevent the default delete behavior
        event.preventDefault();
        if (el.classList.contains('highlight')) {
          // remove the element
          el.remove();
        } else {
          el.classList.add('highlight');
        }
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  event.target.querySelectorAll('span.label.highlight').forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.remove('highlight');
  })
});
```

```css
[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.4em 0;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
  max-height: 1.4em;
  max-width: 1.4em;
}

.selectable-icons img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.label.highlight {
  background: #E1ECF4;
  border: 1px dotted #39739d;
}

span.label {
  background: #E1ECF4;
  border: 1px dotted #39739d;
}
```

```html
<p>Just click on an icon to add it.</p>

<div class="custom-input">
  <div class="selectable-icons">
    <span class="label"> Tag </span>
    <span class="label"> Tag 2 </span>
    <span class="label">Tag 3</span>
  </div>
  <div contenteditable="true">
    You can type here. Add an icon.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works good. Please suggest a way in which I can user editable textarea instead of div @kukkuz

Comment: no issue. Can you add a functionality where in if I change tag data reflects on editable div

Comment: changing the text of tags is not reflecting in the editable div? well, I guess that can be another SO question if what you are stuck with that :)

Comment: added a [link  ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692016/what-should-i-add-here-if-the-content-of-tags-are-changed-then-it-should-be-refl)