# What should I add here if the content of tags are changed then it should be reflect in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

When the click me button is clicked the text of the tag will change. Now I want to implement that if the the span text is changed then the similar span if inserted in the div tag should also change.
Link to fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/t7m2nvcn/10/)

```js
document.querySelector('.selectable-icons').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 
    document.querySelector('[contenteditable]').appendChild(e.target.cloneNode(true));
  
});

document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = function () { document.getElementsByClassName('label')[0].innerHTML = 'new text';
 };
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    // Check for a backspace
    if (event.which == 8) {
        s = window.getSelection();
        r = s.getRangeAt(0)
        el = r.startContainer.parentElement
        // Check if the current element is the .label
        if (el.classList.contains('label')) {
            // Check if we are exactly at the end of the .label element
            if (r.startOffset == r.endOffset && r.endOffset == el.textContent.length) {
                // prevent the default delete behavior
                event.preventDefault();
                if (el.classList.contains('highlight')) {
                    // remove the element
                    el.remove();
                } else {
                    el.classList.add('highlight');
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    event.target.querySelectorAll('span.label.highlight').forEach(function(el) { el.classList.remove('highlight');})
});
```

```css
[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.4em 0;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
  max-height: 1.4em;
  max-width: 1.4em;
}

.selectable-icons img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.label.highlight {
  background: #E1ECF4;
  border: 1px dotted #39739d;
}

span.label {
  background: #E1ECF4;
  border: 1px dotted #39739d;
}
```

```html
<p>Just click on an icon to add it.</p>

<div class="custom-input">
  <div class="selectable-icons">
    <span class="label"> I 1 </span> 
    <span class="label">I  2</span> 
      <span class="label">I  3</span>  
  </div>
  <div contenteditable="true">
    You can type here. <span class="label"> I 1 </span>  Add an icon.
  </div>
</div><input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme"   />
```

Note : Please dont give any suggestion for adding an event to clickme button. I need it just when the span text changes.The button is only for reference. It should be an event on change of span text. If the tag is removed and its still added in text box there should be a tooltip saying missing. It would be great if solution is using meteor js blaze react js.